# Who can tell me what's wrong with this RPGLE-array?

Tags: arrays, printing, ibm-midrange, rpgle, packed-decimal

In have a printer file that looks somewhat like this:

```
Customer-data                 Units01 Units02 ....... Units11
-------------------------------------------------------------
Name/address/zip/....         Count01 Count02 ....... Count11
Name/address/zip/....         Count01 Count02 ....... Count11
:    :       :   :            :       :       :       : 
Name/address/zip/....         Count01 Count02 ....... Count11
                              ------- ------- ------- -------
Totals                        Total01 Total02 ....... Total11
```

The Units, Count and Total fields are mapped into data structures overlayed with an array definition like this:

```
0014.00 D UNITSDS         DS
0015.00 D   UNITS01
0016.00 D   UNITS02
:       :   :
0024.00 D   UNITS10
0025.00 D   UNITS11
0026.00 D  UNITSAR                            LIKE(UNITS) DIM(11) 
0026.00 D                                     OVERLAY(UNITSDS)
:       D*-------------------------------------------------------
0034.00 D COUNTDS         DS
0035.00 D   COUNT01
0036.00 D   COUNT02
:       :   :
0044.00 D   COUNT10
0045.00 D   COUNT11
0046.00 D  COUNTAR                            LIKE(COUNT) DIM(11) 
0046.00 D                                     OVERLAY(COUNTDS)
:       D*-------------------------------------------------------
0054.00 D TOTALDS         DS
0055.00 D   TOTAL01
0056.00 D   TOTAL02
:       :   :
0064.00 D   TOTAL10
0065.00 D   TOTAL11
0066.00 D  TOTALAR                            LIKE(TOTAL) DIM(11) 
0066.00 D                                     OVERLAY(TOTALDS)
```

When I process a WRITE on the details line in the printer file after some processing I get a "Decimal data error".

I was very much surprised that it appears that the arrays COUNTAR and TOTALAR have data type "Packed" although all previous defined variables COUNT, COUNTnn, TOTAL and TOTALnn are "Zoned" and the data structures COUNTDS and TOTALDS are "Char".

Packed data was mapped in the output buffer for the printer file causing the "Decimal data error".

Why are these arrays suddenly in "Packed" data format?

Comment: I would code this.  I'd bet total and count are defined differently like you said.

like(units01) dim(11)
like(counts01) dim(11)
like(total01) dim(11)

Answer (score 0):

Data structures all always character, since RPG doesn't have a BYTE data type.

You don't seem to be defining the subfields here, so they must be picking up there size and type from someplace else.  Likely, the printer file.  Has the printer file changed perhaps?

I suspect this isn't a zoned vs packed issue.  But would need to see the rest of the definitions and the cross reference from the compile listing to really know what's going on.

Instead, it's likely due to the fact that the DS is not initialized.

From the [manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzasd/dinz.htm#dinz)

> When the INZ parameter is not specified:
>    - Static standalone fields and subfields of initialized data structures are initialized to their RPG default initial values (for
>   example, blanks for character, 0 for numeric).
>    - Subfields of uninitialized data structures (INZ not specified on the definition specification for the data structure) are initialized
>   to blanks (regardless of their data type).

Since you don't have the `INZ` keyword on your DS, they are considered uninitialized and all the subfields of your DS are set to blanks.  Which or course are not valid numbers.

If the report normally runs ok, and prints data in all 11 columns.  You could be seeing an error now if you're trying to run the report in such a way that not all 11 subfields are being loaded; thus leaving some with blanks.  When the system tries to move the data to the output buffer of printer file, you get the decimal data error.

In short, add the `INZ` keyword to your DS.

```
D COUNTDS         DS                  INZ
```

Answer (score 0):

I would code this

```
0014.00 D UNITSDS         DS
0015.00 D   UNITS01
0016.00 D   UNITS02
:       :   :
0024.00 D   UNITS10
0025.00 D   UNITS11
0026.00 D  UNITSAR                            LIKE(UNITS01) DIM(11) 
0026.00 D                                     OVERLAY(UNITSDS)
:       D*-------------------------------------------------------
0034.00 D COUNTDS         DS
0035.00 D   COUNT01
0036.00 D   COUNT02
:       :   :
0044.00 D   COUNT10
0045.00 D   COUNT11
0046.00 D  COUNTAR                            LIKE(COUNT01) DIM(11) 
0046.00 D                                     OVERLAY(COUNTDS)
:       D*-------------------------------------------------------
0054.00 D TOTALDS         DS
0055.00 D   TOTAL01
0056.00 D   TOTAL02
:       :   :
0064.00 D   TOTAL10
0065.00 D   TOTAL11
0066.00 D  TOTALAR                            LIKE(TOTAL01) DIM(11) 
0066.00 D                                     OVERLAY(TOTALDS)
```